# (Laravel) Update interface every time there is a change in the database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, optimization

I'm new to Laravel, I want to update the interface every time there is a change in the database but I think calling a JavaScript every 5s to update the interface is not very efficient, so I wonder what is the most efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using some for of websocket to create a connection between your backend and JavaScript based UI?

Either https://laravel.com/docs/master/broadcasting or https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets would allow you to notify your UI to request the updates from your Laravel backend.

My personal suggestion would be that you JS would receive a notification that something had changed and then have to obtain the updated information via Ajax so that you are not sending confidential information through Pusher's servers.